# AutoFixture: Supply a Func as a constructor argument

Tags: c#, autofixture

I am quite new to unit testing and am doing some experiments with xUnit and AutoFixture.

This is the constructor of the class I want to test:

```
public PokerClientIniGenerateCommand(
    Func<TextWriter> writerCreator,
    FranchiseInfo franchise)
{
    // some code here
}
```

I am doing this:

```
public abstract class behaves_like_poker_client_ini_generate_command : Specification
{
    protected PokerClientIniGenerateCommand commandFixture;

    protected behaves_like_poker_client_ini_generate_command()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        commandFixture = fixture.Create<PokerClientIniGenerateCommand>();
    }
}
```

I am not sure how can I set the constructor parameters ( mainly the first parameter - the func part).

In my business logic I am instantiating this class like this:

```
new PokerClientIniGenerateCommand(
    () => new StreamWriter(PokerClientIniWriter),
    franchise));
```

so in my test I should call the func like this:

```
() => new StringWriter(PokerClientIniWriter)
```

But how can I set this via the AutoFixture. Any help will example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From version 2.2](http://megakemp.com/2011/08/01/anonymous-delegates-in-autofixture/) and above, AutoFixture handles `Func` and `Action` delegates automatically.

In your example, you only have to inject a `StringWriter` type as a `TextWriter` type, as shown below:

```
fixture.Inject<TextWriter>(new StringWriter());
```

You can read more about the `Inject` method [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/ec513c654b5b71db4f3ec377b837dd4386ccebf5/Src/AutoFixture/FixtureRegistrar.cs#L11-75).

Comment: What if the Func takes a parameter? ie: ```Func<int,TextWriter>```.  Can you tell Autofixture what to do with the parameter?

Comment: With `Func<int, TextWriter> func = x => new StringWriter();` you can do `fixture.Inject<TextWriter>(func(fixture.Create<int>()));`.

Comment: Ok yea when I asked the question i didn't realize you could just explicitly inject a Func<>, thanks

Answer (score 5):

As @NikosBaxevanis correctly points out in his answer, AutoFixture is able to create [anonymous instances of any delegate type](http://megakemp.com/2011/08/01/anonymous-delegates-in-autofixture). These *anonymous delegates* take the form of dynamically generated methods.

The generation strategy, as it's currently implemented, follows these rules:

1. If the delegate's signature is `void`, the created method will be a
   *no-op*.
2. If the delegate's signature has a return value `T`, the created method will return an anonymous instance of `T`.

Given these rules, in the case of `Func<TextWriter>` it would be enough to just customize the creation of anonymous `TextWriter` objects with:

```
fixture.Register<TextWriter>(() => new StringWriter());
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do this:

```
fixture.Register<Func<TextWriter>>(() => () => new StringWriter());
```